# AMD-V doesn't work

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hardware-virtualization

I need to run a Linux distro (debian) in Virtual machine, but AMD-V just doesn't work.
Any idea why?
 I've tried using Virtualbox and VMware.
Virtualization in BIOS is enabled.

**Here are my specs:**

Motherboard: Gigabyte MA78GM-UD2H
Processor: AMD Athlon II 250

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how AMD-V doesn't work.  In Virtualbox, if the VM won't start when you enable AMD-V, and Virtualbox says "AMD-V is already in use" or similar, with error code VERR_SVM_IN_USE, then there's a [workaround](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5639): set

```
VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE=true
```

in your environment (I actually have VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE=1 and it works for me).  Note that Virtualbox says this is dangerous:  if another hypervisor really is already using AMD-V, you'll bring your host down by trying to share it.  But if not, it's safe - I've been using it for years with my Gigabyte board.

When I filed a ticket with Virtualbox about this problem, they told me that they believe it's caused by buggy BIOSes, and they said old Gigabyte boards are especially prone to it.

The preferred option is to update your BIOS to fix the problem there, but for the board you mentioned, I'm guessing there are no more BIOS updates available.